# "much more" or "far more"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, comparative

1: What is difference between "much more" or "far more"?

2: Is the incorrect sentence, below I mentioned, really wrong?

3: If so, how should I use "much more" or "far more"?

> **Incorrect:** Since her husband began playing violin, Molly has become **much more** expert in distinguishing a tuned instrument from an out of tune one, a Stradivarius from a student rental.
>
> **Correct:** Since her husband began playing violin, Molly has become **far more** expert in distinguishing a tuned instrument from an out of tune one, a Stradivarius from a student rental.

Comment: Whoever told you that the example with *much* is 'Incorrect' was wrong. Both *much* and *far* may be used here, and there's no difference in meaning. *Far* is a touch more literary than *much*.

Comment: If it is from the same GRE book that you mentioned before, I advise you to throw it away.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but if you change the context, _much more_ could actually be wrong. For instance in sentences where you should use _many more_. _Far more_ could be used in both cases,

Comment: @Rathony whatever you said is right. I am a learner of English. I need something to guide me. 90 percent of the book follow strict grammar rules. So leave that

Comment: Well, I remember you said the book you are reading can't go wrong. The above sentence proves again that it can go wrong. Whoever wrote that book doesn't know what they are talking about. It's up to you.

Comment: @Rathony I have ELL to clarify my doubt so I don't go behind the [book](http://www.manhattanreview.com/download/MR-GMAT-Sentence-Correction-Guide.pdf)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40202/discussion-between-aryf-and-rathony).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to have to agree with the several folks who have commented, and use [an English Language and Usage question that talked about *much more*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13880/usage-of-much-more), to bolster the common consensus:

> ***Much more*** being used in this context is no different than ***far more***.

You're also using the correct word with respect to the noun ***expertise*** being considered "uncountable" and thus the appropriate word to use being ***much***; were the noun being discussed a countable one (like apples, fingers, cars, etc), the appropriate word would instead be ***many***.